# Extracting OS name and version number in Makefile

Tags: bash, ubuntu, makefile

I want to set up some environment variable in the makefile only if the system is Ubuntu 11.04 or higher.
I am able to extract the OS name  using
`cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DISTRIB_ID| cut -d "=" -f 2`
and version number using
`cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DISTRIB_RELEASE| cut -d "=" -f 2`

So in my makefile I do

`OSNAME := $(shell cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DISTRIB_ID| cut -d "=" -f 2)`

I get the error that `/etc/lsb-release` not found.

My approach 2 was to use `lsb_release -si` and `-sr` , although these commands works fine in the terminal, the below prints that Ubuntu not found in a Makefile

```
ifeq ($(shell lsb_release -si),Ubuntu)  
     $(info YES UBUNTU DETECTED)
else
     $(info NO UBUNTU DETECTED)
endif
```

What am I doing wrong is there a clean way conditionally setup environment variables is the system is Ubuntu 11.04 or higher?

Comment: Have you tried using `uname` instead?

Comment: If your Makefile is intended only for Ubuntu Linux, then you may check `lsb_release --release`. But actually it's rather strange. Usually you should check if a particular _feature_ like library with headers or an executable exists in a target system.

Comment: @Axel uname is not helpful, no ubuntu release version.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/214930); *why* do you need to detect if the OS is Ubuntu 11.04 or higher?

Comment: @chepner didn't know what a XY problem was... thanks for the link, Will update the problem (i.e X)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
if [ -f /etc/lsb-release ]; then
    . /etc/lsb-release
    OS=$DISTRIB_ID
    VER=$DISTRIB_RELEASE
else
    OS=$(uname -s)
    VER=$(uname -r)
fi

echo $OS
echo $VER
```

Or like this sort command

```
OS=$(lsb_release -si)
ARCH=$(uname -m | sed 's/x86_//;s/i[3-6]86/32/')
VER=$(lsb_release -sr)

echo $OS
echo $VER
echo $ARCH
```

Or in makefile you require like this

```
UNAME_OS := $(shell lsb_release -si)

ifeq ($(UNAME_OS),Ubuntu)
     $(info YES UBUNTU DETECTED)
else
     $(info NO UBUNTU DETECTED)
endif
```

Comment: I can solve my problem if I were using shell script, but I am having issues doing the same in a Makefile... anyways I was able to modify your 2nd approach in the Makefile, it seems to be working will update the modified version

Comment: @Deepthought If you get the answer then accept the answer.

Comment: You can easily embed arbitrarily complex shell script in a `Makefile` (though putting arbitrarily complex shell script in a separate file is probably a good idea); just escape all the dollar signs by doubling them, and all the newlines by putting a backslash just before them. You may simplify things a bit by replacing newlines with semicolons.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for suggestion. Not tried it but will check.